# Android - JAVA Denial of Service: Parse Double

Tags: java, android

There is a vulnerability in implementations of `java.lang.Double.parseDouble()` and related methods that can cause the thread to hang when parsing any number in the range

```
[2^(-1022) - 2^(-1075) : 2^(-1022) - 2^(-1076)]
```

This is not an issue when using java version 6 Update 24 or later.

So in order to develop a secure android application, is it enough to make sure that APK is built on using a JDK whose version is 1.6u24 and above?
OR, this issue is also related to the Android Dalvik VM?

Please help in clarifying as I might have misconceptions.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: You are right. i will do it, but further explanation from the community would help in a better understanding. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buid version of the Java byte code is irrelevant, as long as the execution is done on a JVM with a new parseDouble, or on Dalvik VM, where I do not know of it having this flaw. This is, as the parseDouble code is a runtime library, not part of your code.

The bug is hangs the app up (critical), but is not a security risk as such.

Comment: Considering "availability" is part of security, this can definitely be considered a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

> is it enough to make sure that APK is built on using a JDK whose version is 1.6u24 and above?

If your assessment is correct, and that the JVM bug is in the *implementation* of a method, then no. The only sorts of bugs that would get fixed this way would be due to incorrect bytecodes being generated, and in this case, you aren't compiling the `Double` class yourself -- that's precompiled.

> OR, this issue is also related to the Android Dalvik VM?

I have no idea. You would have to run your own experiments, then determine if it is worth worrying about in your environment.